# How do I turn a float into a stringer in python?(Jupyter Notebook/Google Colab)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

How do I turn a a float into a string? Hey guys, I've been trying to turn the column ileads_address into a string. In all the addresses, there's a .0 behind them. But when I did turn the float into the string, it didn't take away the 0s. Anyone know how to fix this.

'''df4['ileads_address'] = df4['ileads_address'].astype(str)'''

[-----> csv sample file here][1]

edit: Yes I am looking for an integer representation!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyJJJ.png

Comment: Do you want an integer representation? `df['ileads_address'].astype(int).astype(str)`?

Comment: @mozway Yes an integer representation, I tried that code and it didn't work.  Error message: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5017.0'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for type casting.

If column `ileads_address` is a `float`:

```
df4['ileads_address'] = df['ileads_address'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

First you type cast into integer, which removes the `.0`, then into string.

If column `ileads_address` is a `str`:

```
df4['ileads_address'] = df['ileads_address'].astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)
```

First you type cast into float, then integer, which removes the `.0`, then into string.

Reproduceable example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1.3','1.4','1.6']})
print(df)

df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: I'm getting a value error, "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5017.0".

Comment: Then your data frame does not contain floats in that column. Right?

Comment: Use df.dtypes to verify data type of each column.

Comment: Yes it doesn't. I still don't know why I can't rid of the .0.

Comment: The ileads_address in df4.dtypes turned into object.

Comment: try: `df4['ileads_address'] = df['ileads_address'].astype(float).astype(int).astype(str) `

Comment: Here is the error that I'm getting. "IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Comment: This error is out of scope of your question as you provided only a screenshot of two lines which contain something numeric. Your errors seems to be something else. Maybe you have empty fields. The best thing you can do now it cleaning up your data frame. Then the solution above will work for your :) If you have more trouble by cleaning up, please open another question.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see that what I provided works as expected. I think you can accept my answer for now. And no worries. There is always an explanation to some errors, and with the time you will be faster understanding these if you make it over the first frustrating moments :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df4['ileads_address'] = df['ileads_address'].apply(str)
```